# How to search within a BitBucket wiki?

Tags: repository, bitbucket

Having a wiki in a BitBucket project, is it possible to search within that wiki? the purpose of this is to have the project documentation and be able to search for specific terms on that wiki. If it is not possible, is there any cloud based service which allows to upload documentation pages providing search functionality?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to apply search filters like "ext:md" which filters files with ".md" extension which are the markdown pages of the wiki, that do the trick.

Update:

[Link to official documentation about search filters](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/search-873876782.html)

Comment: it sucks that they've never done a wiki specific search, but this tip works pretty well.

Comment: it only seems to work with .md files that are part of the source code; since they have a separate repository for wiki pages, it doesn't seem to work for those pages

Comment: Yeah not sure this is answers the actual question asked. It doesn't search in the wiki, as far as I can tell.